# In a Redis replication environment, slave data cannot be referenced when the master fails

Tags: redis, database-replication

I built a Redis replication environment as follows.

Redis version: 7.0.11
Contents of redis.conf (Master)

```
     appendonly yes
     protected-mode no
     log level verbose
```

Contents of redis.conf (Slave)

```
     protected-mode no
     replica of xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx 6379
     log level verbose
```

The command below confirms that the Slave is successfully connected to the Master.

```
$ redis-cli -h <Slave hostname> -a <password> info replication
# Replication
role: slave
master_host:<Master host name>
master_port: 6379
master_link_status:up
```

Shut down the master node for failure testing.
Then, the slave node has the following status.

```
$ redis-cli -h <Slave hostname> -a <password> info replication
# Replication
role: slave
master_host:<Master host name>
master_port: 6379
master_link_status: down
master_last_io_seconds_ago: -1
master_sync_in_progress: 0
slave_read_repl_offset: 1
slave_repl_offset: 1
master_link_down_since_seconds: -1
slave_priority: 100
slave_read_only: 1
replica_announced: 1
connected_slaves: 0
master_failover_state: no-failover
master_replid: 1a0d017c075b17ec90260ba0c9fcfc9b842eef6b
master_replid2: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
master_repl_offset: 0
second_repl_offset: -1
repl_backlog_active: 0
repl_backlog_size: 1048576
repl_backlog_first_byte_offset: 0
repl_backlog_histlen: 0
```

`Master_link_status: down` will disconnect the connection, but `master_link_down_since_seconds: -1` is displayed.
When I referred to Key in this state, it became (nil).

After that, I tried the same procedure to cause the failure, but I was not able to reproduce the above condition. (Slave returns data normally even if connection with Master is lost)

question

1. In a Redis Replication environment, under what conditions will the data become inaccessible in the Slave when a failure occurs in the Master?
2. Also, what does `master_link_down_since_seconds:-1` mean?